# Twitter Bootstrap 3 List Group

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap for a project.

I have a widget type `list-group`, which is a list of elements that are used for navigation.

For some reason I can't make those links to work. Although the correct link appears when hovering, they don't take me there.

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pando/71qtz89n/1/) to ilustrate the problem.

Can anyone help?

Regards.

Comment: Found the problem. There was a JS with a preventDefault statement. Commenting that out fixed the issue. I copied that code from an external source and didn't realized the issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you specify http in the link it will not work in an https site.

[image: Mixed content error]

Comment: Perhaps it is a side effect of running it on fiddle. My site is not HTTPS and it isn't working either

Answer (score 1):

Never put http protocols in the href for many reasons, one of which the protocol might be the wrong one ! (http vs https).

As for the internal link it is working properly in the JSfiddle once you actually create an element with that id.

Plus the list group should be in a LIST not a bunch of divs

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-basic) for list-group.  When I put your links into a `UL`, things seem to work:

```
<ul class="list-group">
   <li><a 
      href="http://www.google.com" 
      class="list-group-item active"
      >External link not working</a></li>
      <li><a 
      href="#my_local_anchor" 
      class="list-group-item active">
      Internal link not working
   </a> </li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the internal link and it worked when yo use your anchor as an ID

```html
<h1 id="my_local_anchor">
```

And the external link worked when I added:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
```

Which opens the link in a new tab which is usually better as your website will keep a presence in the users browser